# Versioning Model objects in Microsoft Web API 2

Tags: rest, mvvm, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I've been searching and have not found a straight forward answer to this issue.

I have a controller that has a Get method that returns a customer model with 10 fields in it.
The method is versioned at v1.

Now I'm changing the customer model to return 25 fields and have changed the controller Get method to fetch the 25 fields.
It is now v2.

Since the model does not get versioned, when i look at swagger or any other 'self documenting' product for my controller, when i look at v2 the model has 25 fields...all good

When I look at v1 the model still has 25 fields as it did not get versioned so it is incorrect and misleading since the Get method in v1 will only return 10 of the 25 fields.

Does anyone know a solution to this which doesn't force me to create a new model with a different name each time i add fields?  Obviously removing fields is a bigger issue as it would break the consumers code.